# I don't understand why my image point is wrong(teacher said not to graph)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

> The point $(1,4)$ is on the graph of $y = f(x)$. Determine the
>   coordinates of the image of this point on the graph of
>   $y=3f(-4(x+1))-2$.

I divided $1$ by $-4$  and subtracted $1$ from that, which gave me $-\frac{5}{4}$ for the $x$-value. I multiplied $4$ by $3$ and subtracted $2$ and got $10$ for the $y$-value so the image point should be $(-\frac{5}{4},10)$. However, the back of the textbook says $(-5,10)$. What did I do wrong?

Comment: the answer on https://ca.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110302162228AA3bNd5 seems correct to me

Comment: Then why does it differ from the textbook answer?

Comment: Maybe the textbook provides the definition of $f$?

Comment: I don't understand.  Are you saying that the textbook thinks (-5,10) is the definition of f?

Comment: Does the textbook say anything about $f$, like $f(x) = x+3$? If not, does the textbook give any examples of similar questions?

Comment: If I'm to hazard a guess: the _only_ information given of $f$ is $f(1) = 4$. Building off of this, the only thing that can be said with certainty of $ 3f(-4(x+1))-2$ is that $3f(1)-2 = 10$. So if we call $g(x) := 3f(-4(x+1)) -2$, then $g\left(-\frac{5}{4}\right) = 10$ or $ \left(-\frac{5}{4}, 10\right)$ is on the graph of $y = g(x)$.

Comment: LinAlg, it just says (-5,10). It doesn't mention anything about f it anything else. Sirzh, that's what I got too. Do you think the textbook's answer is a mistake?